# How to rename a file by handle on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

On Windows, how can I rename a file using only its handle?

I do not control how the file is opened (it is done through a proprietary third-party library). However I can retrieve a handle to this file (See #1).

Also I know that the proprietary library opens the file with the following attributes:

`GENERIC_WRITE | GENERIC_READ` and `FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_READ`.

I have tried using the `SetFileInformationByHandle` function with `FileRenameInfo` as parameter. Unfortunately this seems to work only if the file was opened with the DELETE access type which is not the case here.

Do you have any ideas if there is a way to do what I want?

Thanks in advance.

#1: Note that the library does not give direct access to the file handle. However it gives me the file name and path. I then retrieve the handle using the NtQuerySystemInformation and NtQueryObject functions. NtQuerySystemInformation allows me to retrieve the list of all handles for the current process (using value 16 for the SystemInformationClass parameter), and then I use NtQueryObject to find the exact handle opens by the library based on its filepath. So I am not opening a separate handle.

```
/* Here is a basic pseudo-code demonstrating what I am trying to achieve */

library::Initialize(); //This creates a new file with a random name. The library keeps a handle opens internally until we call library::close.

file_info_struct tFileInfo;
library::GetFileInfo(tFileInfo); //This gives me information about the created file

HANDLE hFile = my::GetHandleFromFilePath(tFileInfo.file_path); //This function uses NtQuerySystemInformation and NtQueryObject functions to retrieve the existing handle

my::RenameFileByHandle(hFile, someNewFileName); //This is what I am missing. I do not know how to rename the file using its handle

//Carry on with using the library
....

library::close(); //This will close the internal file handle
```

Comment: What language? If you're trying this using .NET you could research [PInvoke](http://pinvoke.net/).

Comment: I'm using c++ but  it is more of a Windows API question regardless of the language used.

Comment: Consider using a process-level hook to intercept the DLL's call to CreateFile.  You could then change the access attributes, or just replace the filename the DLL provides with the one you want.

Comment: @Harry: I am actually considering it but before going down that path, I wanted to be sure there was no other way. I was thinking of using Microsoft Detours for that but I do not know whether it will do the job. Do you have any other libraries to recommend? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

[SetFileInformationByHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365539%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), the proper way to access NtSetInformationFile, new in Vista .

Answer (score 3):

Use [NtSetInformationFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff567096%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with [FileRenameInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540344%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) info class. Note that the handle must be opened with DELETE access.

Answer (score 2):

Use API call [GetFinalPathNameByHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364962%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get file name and then with [MoveFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365239%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API rename the file.

But I think that you should close that file after you get the file name or Move / Rename operation will fail

Comment: MoveFile will not let me rename the file if I do not close the handle before. But closing the handle is not an option since the proprietary library will need it to write to the file.

Comment: well, I think that this is not possible since MoveFile will fail if file is allready open

Comment: Moving an opened file, even if it is locked, will succeed as long as it stays on the same drive.

Comment: @ben: you say the library requires the handle. Are you opening the handle yourself and giving it to the library, or are you asking the library to give you the handle, or are you hacking the library and extracting the handle directly? If #1 or #3, then you have direct access to the original handle variable, so just close it, move the file, open a new handle, and assign it back to the variable.

Comment: @Hans: MoveFile returns with and error even if it is on the same drive: "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process"

Comment: @Remy: Actually I am not opening the handle myself. The library does it internally. The only thing the library allows me to retrieve is the name/path of the file it creates. I then have a way, using the windows API, to retrieve the file handle the library is using. So I'm neither #1 or #3, but I'm kind of #2 with an indirect way to retrieve the file handle.

Comment: You cannot MoveFile a file while it is open. You can do this `MoveFileEx(szSrcFile, szDstFile, MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT);
` but it will do the rename only during the next reboot and that's probably not what you want.

Comment: @ben: then you are not actually accessing the library's original handle at all. You are using the library's provided filename to open a separate handle to the same file that the library has a handle to. That is a different scenario, in which case you are basically SOL.

Comment: @Remy: No I am not opening a separate handle. I am retrieving the handle used by the library using the NtQuerySystemInformation and NtQueryObject function. NtQuerySystemInformation allows me to retrieve the list of all handles for the current process (using value 16 for the SystemInformationClass parameter), and then I use NtQueryObject to find the exact handle opens by the library based on its filepath.

Comment: @ben: This is relevant information that should have been given up front. Please update your question with it, as well as a code snippet demonstrating exactly how you are using them.

Comment: @ben indeed it is important, as you are getting the handle in a non-direct way. I bet you are on a different process too?